# FFmpeg has no bin folder to link to or .exe file. How do I use it?

Tags: ffmpeg

Installation instructions say to create a path for c:\ffmpeg\bin, but when I try to run it, I keep getting an error saying "ffmpeg is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program, or batch file"

I've tried removing the last backslash, leaving out "bin", I double-checked and the ffmpeg folder is in C:. I've already tried searching various forums about how to go about this and they all say to download a Zeranoe (?) build which is the one that has a bin folder? But upon checking, that was taken down last September.

One of the forums said to just create a path to whichever folder has the .exe file, but I can't find any .exe file in the folder. There are a lot of .c files scattered across different folders so I'm not sure what to do now.

I couldn't find any forums, threads, or instructions for installing this after the Zeranoe build was taken down.

Comment: What you have downloaded is the source code of ffmpeg. An EXE file is generated by compiling those source files. But preparing the correct compile environment is not that easy. Better search the net for an already compiled version for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg only provides source code and does not offer any `.exe`.

You can download `ffmpeg.exe` for Windows from [Gyan](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) or [BtBN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases).